# Navbar active using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have this one problem regarding the highlighted navbar menu which will only highlight when we clicked on it. For that to work, I'm using javascript. However, each pages has its own sub pages, for example, page Home has a link of local/home, but its content will lead to local/home/content. The sub link will not make the navbar to function The navbar was coded in different file, which I just extends in the home and other pages. I'm not very good at explaining but if I can elaborate more on any part I would do so. Below I attached my JS and my navbar:

HTML :

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ url('/') }}">Home
                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('courses') }}">opportunities</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('events') }}">events</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('uqalc') }}">courses</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('contact') }}">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

JS :

```
const currloc = location.href;
        const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        const menuLen = menuItem.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < menuLen; i++) {
            menuItem[i].classList.remove('active');
            if (menuItem[i].href === currloc) {
                menuItem[i].className = "nav-link active";
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you want to ask? Do you mean you want to make `nav` js file and load it on each page?

Comment: Yes, also in subpages

Comment: If `nav` element is opened while surfing in your website then adding and removing class should be fired when the menus are clicked. So starting with `nav.addEventListener('click', func)` can make the js function.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read from your question, you want the navbar to change color when clicked. This can be easily accomplished in two different ways.

The first is making a `#Active` id that would be given to the proper navbar link on every page. (More [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_active))

The second is if you are staying on the same page but still want the button to change color when clicked. (More [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp))

Either way is effective.

---

Have questions? Comment download below. Like my answer? Give me a checkmark and up-vote.